# Fetch and save a copy of a QuerySet with a new User field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a number of models, each with a user field. Each time a new user is registered I want to copy the instances of these models which have user.id = 1, and save them with a new user id in the user field. I've read that a copy of a model instance can be made by setting the `pk` to `None` so this is what I've tried to do first. I'm trying to do this on a `QuerySet` since there are many instances for some tables (over 1000 for some models, though mostly less than 100).

```
def copy_tables(user):
    # This approach fails with "Voice has no field named 'pk'"
    voice = Voice.objects.filter(user=1).update(
        pk=None, user=user.id, right_answers=0, wrong_answers=0)
```

I've also tried using `copy.deepcopy(Voice.objects.filter(user=1))` but calling `update()` on this is also still changing the original table in the database.

```
def copy_tables(user):
    copy.deepcopy(Voice.objects.filter(user=1)).update(
        user=user.id, right_answers=0, wrong_answers=0)
    # This test throws an error because the original models have been changed
    assert Voice.objects.filter(user=1).first()
```

Am I missing some other way of doing this? Also, I thought that all model instances had a primary key, `pk`, which is automatically set by Django. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling the `save` method on a model instance, Django determines if it must be inserted or updated by checking if it has a primary key ([ref.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert)).

So if you set the PK to None on a model instance, Django will trying adding it as a new row in the database.

Demo:

```
# Retrieve the object belonging to the user whose ID is 1.
# Note that you cannot use "user=1", you need to tell Django you
# are querying by id, using "user__id=1" .
obj = MyModel.objects.get(user__id=1) 

# Set PK to None so that Django thinks it is not save in the database.
obj.pk = None

# Save to insert it.
obj.save()
```

In your case where you have multiple objects, you can use [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to gain in performances:

```
voices = Voice.objects.filter(user__id=1)
new_voices = []
for voice in voices:
    voice.pk = None
    voice.user = user
    right_answsers = 0
    wrong_anwsers = 0
    new_voices.append(voice)

Voice.objects.bulk_create(new_voices)
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to do in the `update` in my first approach. Can this not be done as an update to a QuerySet? The `Voice.objects.filter(user=1)` part works fine and returns the expected QuerySet.

Comment: @JamieBull no that cannot be done because update will try to act on the existing object in the DB, you want to insert a new one. To do that you make Django to issue an `INSERT` with the values of the previously retrieved object.

Comment: So I need to loop through everything rather than being able to do this is one SQL-type statement?

Comment: @JamieBull I had not understood that there were many objects linked to user one, I will edit my answer accordingly.